# Available Serial ports are not shown in Visual studio

Tags: c#, windows, serial-port

I am recently working on a project for Serial port communication, I want to show the available serial ports in a comboBox, But while running it is not showing the available list of com ports.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Serial_application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           getPortsNames();
        }
        void getPortsNames()
        {
          string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
          comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you check your available port?

Comment: Are you having trouble accessing ports or displaying them?
Did you check outside of visual studio? Like do those devices you connect through com ports show up in device manager? Can you access them by other means?

Comment: First check the available ports from Device Manager.

Comment: Your code is correct, go to device manager and see if you have any port available in your computer.

Comment: From remarks in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx). *The port names are obtained from the system registry (for example, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM). If the registry contains stale or otherwise incorrect data then the GetPortNames method will return incorrect data.*

Answer (score 0):

There are no old style com ports on most modern computers, they are USB converters. If the USB device driver has not been installed there are no ports listed in the computer. Just solved this problem for myself.